How to interpret Hoeffding's inequality for extreme cases?
What does it mean to have probability 2 by Hoeffding's inequality?
Suppose there is a case where $ S_n = \mathbb E[S_n] $, then the RHS of Hoeffding's inequality collapses to $\leq 2$ which doesn't make a lot of sense mathematically.
Suppose while training a model, for $n = 1$, we want to check if the model generalizes beyond the training examples given, the first thing one would do in this case is to get a theoretical estimate of the probability of memorization - say $50$ of possible $1000$ instances, $p = 1/20$, accuracy, let's say be same as the probability.
Now, the model works with an accuracy $0.5$, which is significantly higher than $0.05$, here, $t = 0.5 - 0.05 = 0.45$, hence, $\mathbb P (0.45 \geq t) \leq 2e^{-2t^{2}}$, we get $\mathbb P(0.45 \geq 0 ) \leq 2$ which makes sense for probability to be more then one, but I seem to be confused if that is the right way to use the inequality.
$\mathbb P (0.45 = 0.45) \leq 2e^{-0.405} = 1.33395...$, which again makes absolutely no sense mathematically.

It makes perfect sense, it just means what it says: the probability is less than or equal to $2$, i.e. you've gained no additional information since all probabilities have this property.

@QiaochuYuan Thank you. That's a very valid point.

I don't think the setup you have described is compatible with Hoeffding's inequality. The inequality treats $S_n$ as a sum of random variables, while you treat it as a constant. There's also the issue of your circular definition of $S_n$ - you've defined the random variable $S_n$ as the expectation of itself.
Perhaps your second and third paragraphs will correct themselves if you treat $S_n$ as a non-constant, random variable. If you insist on treating $S_n$ as constant (maybe as a trivial sum of one random variable that is constant), then the probability will collapse to zero rather than two.

This makes perfect sense. Thank You Joe Driscoll  for your answer. I now get the point of using Hoeffding's inequality in such cases.
